# Run External Command Before JUnit Tests in Eclipse

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, junit, command

Is it possible to run an external command before running tests in a given JUnit file? I run my tests using the Eclipse's Run command. Using JUnit 4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very vague question. Specifically, you didn't mention how you are running your JUnit tests. Also you mentioned 'file', and a file can contain several JUnit tests. Do you want to run the external command before each of those tests, or before any of them are executed?

But more on topic:

If you are using JUnit 4 or greater then you can tag a method with the `@Before` annotation and the method will be executed before each of your tagged `@Test` methods. Alternatively, tagging a static void method with `@BeforeClass` will cause it to be run before any of the `@Test` methods in the class are run.

```
public class MyTestClass {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void calledBeforeAnyTestIsRun() {
        // Do something
    }

    @Before
    public void calledBeforeEachTest() {
       // Do something
    }

    @Test
    public void testAccountCRUD() throws Exception {
    }
}
```

If you are using a version of JUnit earlier than 4, then you can override the `setUp()` and `setUpBeforeClass()` methods as replacements for `@Before` and `@BeforeClass`.

```
public class MyTestClass extends TestCase {

    public static void setUpBeforeClass() {
        // Do something
    }

    public void setUp() {
       // Do something
    }

    public void testAccountCRUD() throws Exception {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your post essentially answers my question, although I was hoping for something that does not rely on the language itself (Run configuration, etc).

Comment: @Petr - no prob. JUnit is a very tight, well defined library (one of the things most people like about it). If you want to customize some kind of external configuration then you have to specify more detail - i.e, are you launching your tests with Maven, Ant, in the IDE etc etc.

Comment: @Petr - nvm I see you edited your question. I don't believe you can configure an external command to run as part of the JUnit invocation. But the other methods I outlined should work just fine.

Comment: I launch the test in the IDE. What I want to do is to remove certain temporary files generated by the tests either before or after running the test suite.

Comment: @Petr You should do that work in the test itself; tests should be 100% self-contained. The method(s) Perception shows is the appropriate way to handle that, although IMO I'd keep it OS-agnostic as well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using JUnit 4.0, you could do the following:

```
@Test
public void shouldDoStuff(){
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("application agrument");
    // Run the rest of the unit test...
}
```

If you want to run the external command for every unit test, then you should do it in the `@Before` setup method.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm the author of TestProcesses.

Just in case someone lands here searching for a solution:

It's been a while since this question was asked. Assuming you have migrated to JUnit5 in the meantime and are using (or can use) Spring Test, you could have a look at [TestProcesses](https://github.com/netmikey/testprocesses). It is a JUnit5 extension that manages the lifecycle of applications/programs (processes) needed during testing.

It sounds like that's what you're looking for and it allows you to manage the process' lifecycle declaratively, without a lot of boilerplate in your test classes.

https://github.com/netmikey/testprocesses